# How to update POJO set using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans-7

Being new to hibernate, I am using netbeans 7.2, Glassfish 3.x, and mysql. From my database schema I use hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.reveng.xml to create the POJOs. The option in Netbeans is `Hibernate Mapping files and POJOs`.

My question is this: Having added a new table to the data, how do I bring it in as a POJO?  I try updating both hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.reveng.xml by hand and do `clean and build` and then `run` but that does not work.

EDIT TO ADD HIBERNATE.CFG.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anims</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mouser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">my password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="ccvd.Photo"/>
    <mapping class="ccvd.Dogs"/>
    <mapping class="ccvd.Cats"/>
    <mapping class="ccvd.Birds"/>
      </session-factory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what all you have done. Here are the basic steps.

A good example is mentioned at the [hibernate website](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html_single/) specially [chapter 2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch02.html).

```
   1. Create POJO class
   2. Create entries in mapping config file
   3. Get Hibernate Session through Hibernate Session Factory
   4. Use session API methods to perform CRUD operation
```

Please Note: Lately there is a trend to use `Annotation` based Entity classes, which simplify the process lot better.

Comment: Can you please share you config file and usage code? That assist in better helping you.

Comment: Actually I am rebuilding it from the example code you provide. I see the following lines in the example: `<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`. I am using MySQL with Glassfish 3.1.2 and a database named `socialdb`. Is it possible to change the `.cfg.xml` file to create the db or must the db already exist so that only the tables are created?

Comment: If you have already created the tables, don't recreate it. In standard applications, you don't do that.

Comment: I am actually trying to learn this first: proof of concept before actually creating the project. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to add resource in mapping

```
<mapping class="ccvd.Birds" resource="a/b/c.java"/>
```

and that a/b/c.java is your class in package with . replaced by / and that whole entry represented the mapping of a class to a file.

1 tips,I highly recomanded using annotation.that is so convenient in development.
just add @entity  on class file  ,and add search path in configure file,everything is done!

Have fun with java web development!